# is there a fast way to plot multiple plots in Scilab

Tags: plot, scilab

Right now I am reading a folder and getting some plot logs. I have about 95 of them, and then I parse the log and plot2d and then animate a block over the positions in the log.    It is taking a few minutes to get all of the plot windows to open. I am currently using the scf to open a new plot window. 
It isn't getting to the 95th plot and not doing any animation, so it appears to be dying right before the end, but there is no output on teh console. 
I am using Scilab 6.0

This is how i am creating the plot. I iterate through this based on how many logs are in the folder.

```
scf(newFolderIndex); 
plot2d(xPosition,yPosition) 
xtitle(logFolders(newFolderIndex))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you don't really need 100+ windows, you can not efficiently view them.
You can do 2 things to prevent freezing and maybe speed up the process:
Open only one graphic window (say 0), then:
1. plot the data
2. save to a file
3. clear the gaphic window
4. repeat from 1.

To speed up the drawing process, you can delay with `drawlater()` the actual display on the screen until the last graphical element is drawn, then issue `drawnow()`. If you have lots of datapoints, and especially multiple plot() commands, this can make a significant difference.

```
for i=1:3
  scf(0);   //set current figure
  clf(0);   //clear figure
  drawlater();  //inhibit actual display on the screen
  plot2d(rand(100,1),rand(100,1),style=-4);
  xtitle(string(i));
  drawnow();    //display now
  xs2png(0,"D:\Attila\PROJECTS\Scilab\Stackoverflow\"+string(i)+".png");    //save to file
  //there are other file formats also, search for xs2jpg, xs2gif...
end
```

Watching the saved files with an image viewer program is much convenient then switching between multiple graphic windows.
Another advantage of the method is that if you resize the graphic window and rerun the program, all the graphs will have the same size. (But of course you may specify the window size explicitly with `f=gcf(); f.figure_size=[200,200];`)

Comment: Ah..good point.  I will have to revisit.    But for now I set ir up and was able to read in a log,  animate the plot...then it went to the next log amd so on and so on....   i am trying to verify vehicle position log and if the vehicle is straighter now than before.

Comment: What image viewer do you suggest?